# FSCalendar function called when month changed

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I have been using https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar recently for a project.

One thing I have been trying to do is call a function whenever the calendar changes months (for example, if the user swipes right or left). However, I can't seem to find any functions that are called when the month on FSCalendar changes.

I tried to override:

`func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {`

But that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I missed something in the documentation. Is there a way to see when the months changes in the FSCalendar package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

5 seconds after posting this, I found

```
func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
    print("changed")
}
```

That solved my problem.